# convert a column of list to dummies by group not character

Tags: python, dummy-variable

I've tried two things so far without luck to convert column values to dummies.

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYrtM.png)

So I'm trying to dummify personal interests.

```
uf = uf['personal_interests'].str.join('|').str.get_dummies()
print(uf)
```

or

```
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

mlb.fit(['body','men_skincare','tools','hand','makeup','hair', 'nail', 'skincare','men_fragrance','fragrance','foot'])

list(mlb.classes_)

print(mlb.classes_)

uf = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(uf['personal_interests']),columns=mlb.classes_, index=uf.index)

print(uf)
```

In both situations I get this:

[Character Dummy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jF9d.png)

Rather than an output like this:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcghC.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [104939, 2, True, ['body', 'makeup', 'nail', 'hand']],
    [123411, 2, True, ['men', 'nail', 'body']],
    [321321, 2, True, ['hand', 'foot', 'nail']]
]
colnames = ['user_id', 'number_', 'ordered_before', 'personal_interests']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=colnames)

interests = sorted(set().union(*[set(pi) for pi in df.personal_interests]))
uf = pd.DataFrame(0, index=df.user_id, columns=interests)
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    uf.loc[row.user_id, row.personal_interests] = 1
print(uf)
```

prints

| user_id | body | foot | hand | makeup | men | nail |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 104939 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 123411 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 321321 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |